# how to chance order of plugins wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

I would like to have my custom plugin on top of the sidebar. Haven't found how the order is made. Now my custom plugin is at the bottom. I would like to move it near the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the menu position with [add_menu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) like this:

```
add_menu_page( 
    __( 'Custom Menu Title', 'textdomain' ),
    'custom menu',
    'manage_options',
    'custompage',
    'my_custom_menu_page',
    plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ),
    6 //choose your Position!!!!
);
```

These are the default values for "position":

- 2 – Dashboard
- 4 – Separator
- 5 – Posts
- 10 – Media
- 15 – Links
- 20 – Pages
- 25 – Comments
- 59 – Separator
- 60 – Appearance
- 65 – Plugins
- 70 – Users
- 75 – Tools
- 80 – Settings
- 99 – Separator

In your case, if you type 0 or 1 in the position field your custom menu will be displayed at the top of the "Dashboard" menu.